# Flex: background-color for htmlText in TextArea?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, stylesheet

Is it possible to assign a background color for a certain text part inside the TextArea? similar Like that

```
<div style="background-color:#FF0000">...</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background color is not woring in htmlText of the TEXTAREA so you need to change the FontColor. I have faced that problem earlier and getting the same result and after googled it a lot i have got the result to change the FONT color instead of changing BACKGROUND Color. but you can bluff that just run the following code by creating new html page

```
<html>
<body>
Hi My name is
<table bgcolor="#777777">
<tr><td>
<font color="red" bgcolor="yellow"><h1>Sagar</h1></font>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and embed the htmlText of the TextArea with that code...

Have a Nice Day....

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The htmlText property supports a very limited subset of HTML. The following tags are supported (more info is available [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html)):

```
- Anchor tag (<a>)
- Bold tag (<b>)
- Break tag (<br>)
- Font tag (<font>)
- Image tag (<img>)
- Italic tag (<i>)
- List item tag (<li>)
- Paragraph tag (<p>)
- Text format tag (<textformat>)
- Underline tag (<u>)
```

True HTML may support additional properties on these tags but Flex will most likely have no support for them.